# Trying to read in a file and get separate pieces of information that are on the same line

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get every separate piece of information from this file, assign it to a variable, create a Customer object using the data and then add it to an array of Customer objects. This is for a project and I have to use arrays, not arraylists, and I have to use 2 scanners in my readCustomerFile method. Need help finishing readCustomerFile, can't figure out what to do with second scanner

Here's the file:

```
1 10001 Smith Sam 34.5 100.0 63.5 350.0
2 10002 Jones Pat 34.5 100.0 63.5 300.0
3 10003 King Kelly 34.5 100.0 63.5 300.0
4 10004 Jenkins Jordan 34.5 100.0 63.5 300.0 100.0
```

The first number is what type of Customer object that person is. 1 is PreferredCustomer, 2 is SilverPreferredCustomer and 3 is GoldPreferredCustomer.
Here's the constructor:

```
public class RewardsProcessor {

   private Customer[] customers;
   private String[] invalidRecords;

   public RewardsProcessor() {

      customers = new Customer[0];
      invalidRecords = new String[0];
   }
```

My readCustomerFile method so far(The one I need help with) This is supposed to use 2 scanners. One to read in the file and the other to go line by line and get the information

```
 public void readCustomerFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

     Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); 
     int category = 0;
     int account = 0;
     String name = " ";
     Double[] purchase = new Double[100];


     while(scanFile.hasNext()) {
         String next = scanFile.nextLine();
```

Here's Customer and PreferredSilverCustomer for refrence

```
public Customer(String acctNumberIn, String nameIn) {

      acctNumber = acctNumberIn;
      name = nameIn;
      purchases = new double[0];

   }


public PreferredSilverCustomer(String acctNumber, String name) {
      super(acctNumber, name);
      category = "Preferred Silver Customer";

   }
```

Comment: (1) Why are you initializing your arrays to empty arrays? `new double[0]` is an array with no elements. (2) What problem are you encountering? An exception? An incorrect output? Where in the code does it happen?

Comment: Step 1) Use a scanner to get the line. Step 2) Parse the line into an array of strings with the command `String[] split_by_spaces = str.split("\\s");`. Step 3) Loop through this new array and make an object according to the values stored in this array. That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answere for how much I understand your question

### Step1)

```
 Scanner readFile=new Scanner(new File(filename);
 String tempValue=""; // used for storing value while access data
 String[] contents=new String[100];
 int i=0;
 while(readFile.hasNextLine())
{  
  contents[i]=readFile.nextLine(); // this array contain all your information in file line by line
  i++;
}
```

### Step2)

Now **contents array** contain your all information in file
to access information in single line
Use

```
String[] information=contents[0].split(" "); // now inforamtion[0] contain 1,inforamtion[1] contain 10001,.....
```